# Using DOS batch file to find data in a CSV or text file

Tags: batch-file, csv, dos

I'm looking for a quick way to look up the information of a line of data from a CSV (or it can be saved in any format). User needs to be prompted to enter the exact Name and the return would be additional details. Example table below.

```
Name | Mfr | Model | Number | Asset | Location | Unit | Install

AOM69-WC-2d HP  PROLIANT DL360 G7   USEX13S5NW  90901X3 F99 85  X2547d5

Roswell-Con-21x HP  PROLIANT DL360P GEN8    USE2O35QP0  8223173 X22 63  V2355863
```

My thought:

```
Enter the Name you are looking for:> AOM69-WC-2d
```

returns the data below:

```
AOM69-WC-2d has the following information: HP   PROLIANT DL360 G7   USEX13S5NW  90901X3 F99 85  X2547d5
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. As a new visitor here, your first step should be to read the guidelines in the [help]. Please pay special attention to the topic [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), particularly item #3 in the numbered list on that page. This isn't a site where you post your requirements and we then churn out the code to meet them. You'll need to at least put forth some effort to solve the problem yourself, and include that effort in your question, if you want help here.

Comment: @DavidCandy:  That is an answer not a comment - post it as an answer.

Comment: Is this actually for MS-DOS or are you in fact talking about a Windows command shell batch file?

Comment: Findstr!? I never used that one. Dude! Sweet! You guys just ROCK! I'll let you know what i get!

Comment: @DavidCandy: That true, I covered that possibility in my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Windows command shell is not a Turing complete programming language, you will find it difficult to do anything very sophisticated without coding helper commands in some other language - in which case you might as well use another language - or using third-party utilities to perform some tasks.

The shortcomings of Windows batch files are largely addressed by [Windows PowerShell](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_PowerShell), but for this application neither are probably the best choice.

You can however *almost* do what you want as follows:

```
@echo off
set /p name=Enter the name you are looking for:>
findstr /c:"%name%" datafile.csv
```

To get the precise output you suggested would need to perform some string processing on the `findstr` output, and there is no support for that in Win32.  You could pipe the output of `findstr` to something like `sed`, a Windows version of which can be found [here](http://unxutils.sourceforge.net/).  PowerShell however supports string handling directly.

Comment: You are incredible! That looks simple! I will try it asap! I LOVE YOU DUDE!

Comment: @user2989284:  Appreciated ;) but the appropriate way to show appreciation is to up-vote and/or accept an answer by clicking the up-vote and/or tick icons.  You can up-vote multiple answers and comments, but accept only one (though you may change the accepted answer), so you might want to wait for other suggestions or to try this one first.